# Cron Job timing Schedule

Tags: php, cron-task

I have a PHP web page which serves the RSS feed, but it takes about 15-20 seconds to generate a response (which then will be cached for 10 minutes on the server for faster responses).

How could I set a cron job timing for this operation? I am having problem with this. I think if I call the page before 10 minutes it will run cached page so I won't get latest updated page, is this true? And if I call that page after 10 mins then will I have to wait for 15-20 seconds to get a response?

How do I manage to make this process where I will get updated feed with swift response? I haven't tried cron job before, this is my first time, so i find this confusing.

My cron command is : `*/10 * * * * wget http//www.example.com/multifeed.php`

Is it right?

Comment: You could do something like `*/10 * * * * php /path/to/script.php > /path/to/rss.xml`. Your cron is usually configured using `crontab -e` but some hosts offer a control panel instead. Yes, if you cache every 10 minutes, then your served RSS will be anywhere between 0-10 minutes old, depending on your cron trigger times and user visit times.

Comment: (Caching is generally a good idea, though 15-20 seconds does sound rather slow, and you may wish to fix that also).

Comment: @halfer it fetches feed from 3rd party site so i believe it needs that much to call 3rd party page and serve. But issue is when should i call the php script to run that page?

Comment: Ah right, third party systems are likely to be slower, OK. I am not sure I understand your subsequent question though - the above line goes in your crontab. Cron runs the script every 10 minutes automatically, and writes an XML file which your web server can serve as-is.

Comment: @halfer cron command is fine but i am facing other problem.

Comment: @halfer sorry i was saying is how to write cron for this process as i dont want to see old feeds from cached page. what should be the calling time for cron script for this prob?

Comment: @halfer i thought i haven't shown respect with my previous comment saying i am facing other problem not stating the exact problem i am having

Comment: @halfer If page is not cached then user gets blank screen because it is taking 15-20 sec. After processing it will be stored for 10 mins but i dont want to see this happening, blank screen. So I am looking for ideal cron job process

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have: (a) how are you triggering your cron process? (b) what is your PHP code? Thanks.

Comment: Does you `multifeed.php` script write data at the end? If so, there should not be a 15-20 second period where the XML file does not exist. If you are deleting the file at the start and writing it at the end, on the other hand, that is your problem.

Comment: I figured out the way for this problem by increasing timeout. I know its not the best practices. So one user has to wait for 15 sec now and others will get faster response. In Multifeed.php i haven't used single line of xml code.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have a perfect cron to bring the fresh data as soon as it's available, That's a limitation you'll have to live with I think.

What I would do is run this cron every 2 minutes and try to get new data, I would check to see if the last update is different than what I already have, and if it is, update the file, if it's not, do nothing and wait for the next cron.

This method will provide at most two minutes of stale data.

Another option is to check the mtime of hte file : http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Basically,  I visit your page, We check the mtime of the file, if it's greater than 10 minutes, we fetch fresh data, this, combined with the cron, can provide a way for users to always see fresh data. If the freshness of the information isn't that important(can you live with two minutes of stale data?), if it's not that important, simply run the two minute cron.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The only caveat is whether the third-party site is happy with 720 requests every day from a single source. It's not a great load, but if the site operators see frequent and regular IP addresses in their logs, they might be inclined to block (especially if each takes 15+ sec to render). In the end, it depends on whether the OP has permission to fetch.

Comment: @halfer I am fetching rss feed from their site what i do is i convert them to full feed that is why it took 15-20 sec time, i guess

Comment: @Roon13 Halfer has a point, If you have a method of fetching the last update time from the server, that would be even better, making requests much cheaper and faster.

Comment: Now i am getting your point. I don't have that implementation so i will work on that first then i will let u know whether it worked or not. Thanks Halfer and Patrik